# Self-programmed things such as annoucements to chat -room?

Tags: support, chat

Unix.SE and Math.SE has totally different chats, Unix.SE gets a stream of questions. How can you add this kind of features/bugs to chat rooms?

Comment: I hadn't noticed this before, but it turns out that any owner of the room can add feeds to the room. There seem to be two options: inline chat and some sort of ticker feed. I suspect that having the stream of questions inline in chat would be a bad idea due to the crazy high volume, but maybe the ticker would be a good experiment. Do you think so?

Comment: @mixedmath yes agree about the inline thing, quite irritating with high-traffic or with discussion. I hope there was more options about programming things such as announcements to chat -room, specific RSS feeds are not done so cannot use them.

Comment: If memory serves, robjohn tried adding a feed to the chatroom for a while, but it was removed after a few users mentioned that it was a bit intrusive.